# Ignore accents using elastic search and tire

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch, tire

I'm inheriting a project that has some elastic search through tire.

The search is working, but accents through it off. Searching for "this" needs to return "thís" and "thiš" for instance.

I have read this tire documentation: http://karmi.github.com/tire/

As well as: http://railscasts.com/episodes/306-elasticsearch-part-1?view=asciicast

Which mentions that most of elastic search's options are available in tire.

Searching regarding ignoring accents, asciifolding kept coming up, but elastic search just has this to say about it:

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/index-modules/analysis/asciifolding-tokenfilter.html

Additionally I found a few things about filters/accents/etc such as these:

https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/890
https://gist.github.com/2142635

But they're all using bare elastic search options.

When I try to use an asciifolding filter in my ruby code, I get an error about no filter defined for "asciifolding".

Here's the guts of the search being done in my code - how can I modify this to do an accent-insenstive search. Is it asciifolding, and if so, how do I declare it here?

```
result = tire.search(:load => true,page: params[:page], per_page: params[:per_page] ) do
  query { string "#{params[:term]}", :default_operator => 'and' }  if params[:term].present?
  filter  :missing,   :field => 'original_media_id' #see above
  #asciifolding?
  sort { by :updated_at, :desc } if params[:term].present?
  facet 'files' do
    terms  'indexed_files.file.id'  
  end
end
```

EDIT: Or perhaps it should done in the mapping/indexing? And then rerun the indexer. Here's the mapping, I've tried putting :filter => "asciifolding" to some of the indexes, but that didn't seem to work (nor generate any error output):

```
tire.mapping do
    indexes :id, :index => :not_analyzed
    indexes :name, :filter => "asciifolding"
    indexes :description, :filter => "asciifolding"
    indexes :created_at, :type => 'date'
    indexes :updated_at, :type => 'date'
    indexes :file_type
    indexes :indexed_files, :type => 'object' do
        indexes :file, :type => 'object', 
            :properties => { 
            :title => {
            :type => "multi_field",
              :fields => {
                :raw => { :type => 'string', :index => 'not_analyzed'},
                :title => { :type => 'string', :filter => "asciifolding" }
              }
            },
            :description => { :type => "string", :filter => "asciifolding" }
           }
    end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

There's a very nice example of "asciifolding" (removing accents from tokens when indexing text) in this article: [**Autocomplete with Tire**](http://dev.af83.com/2012/01/19/autocomplete-with-tire.html)

Comment: Link, u provided, is dead. Here's an alternative one: https://gist.github.com/conikeec/2142635